# How to structure Angular 7 app with multiple modules

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

Please refer the picture attached to understand the project structure. This is a very common angular project structure with different modules protected by AuthGuard and a shared module which will have all core features to be used across all protected modules.

Our application is becoming too large and as per our requirements users cannot access features present in all module. I do feel that there is no need to load all modules (they are developed to be using lazy loading).

I am thinking to provide a middleware page which will contain tiles (Module-1, Module-2 and so on based on permissions) and clicking on the tile will load the angular app with only selected and shared module.

Is there a provision like this in angular 7?

Thank You for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angular v7 has support for mono repo architecture. You can make libraries and share them in projects.

> Please find the link below for reference:
>   *https://github.com/ShubhenduVaid/angularCLI-monorepo*

Another way to approach this is with NX workspace which is build over angular cli.

> Please find the link below for reference:
>   *https://github.com/nrwl/nx*